# Call by value can change the value for main program

Tags: c, call-by-value

Consider the following programs:

```
void f2 ( int * a, int * b) {   
               int c; 
               c = * a;
               *a = *b;
               *b = c; 
} 
int main () { 
        int a = 4, b = 5, c = 6; 
        f2 (&b, &c); 
        printf ("%d", c - a - b);  
 }
```

Here the values of `b` and `c` are getting swapped.

And another code is:

```
# include <stdio.h>
void mystery (int *ptra, int *ptrb) {  
     int *temp; 
     temp = ptrb;  
     ptrb = ptra; 
     ptra = temp; 
} 
int main () { 
    int a = 2016, b=0, c= 4, d = 42; 
    mystery (&a, &b);
    if (a < c) 
          mystery (&c, &a); 
    mystery (&a, &d); 
    printf("%d\n", a); 
}
```

Here, though same type of function call is there, values of any variable in `main()` program does not changed.

As we know, there is no call by reference in C code. So, my question is, though there are same type of function call in both the program, then why one is swapping the values of variable and another cannot swap??

In the second program pointer is swapping means address are also swapping. Right?? But it doesn't affect on value. While in 1st program , address and pointer is swapped and at the mean time values also swapped. But Why??

I also want to know, where call by value, can change the value of main() program (with or without return function)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `f2` in the first program, pointers are being **dereferenced** to change what those pointers point to so that `b` and `c` in the `main` function are modified.  In contrast, `mystery` in the second program is only swapping the values of the local variables `ptra` and `ptrb` which has no effect on the variables in `main`.

So this:

```
ptrb = ptra;
```

Assigned the value of one pointer to another (which are both local to `msytery`), while this:

```
*a = *b;
```

Changes the value of what one pointer *points to* to the value of what another pointer *points to*, namely `a` and `b` in `main`.

Another way to think of this is with houses and their residents:

```
    ______        _____         ______       ______
   /______\      /______\      /______\     /______\
 2 |Smith |    4 |Jones |    6 | Bond |   8 | Solo |
   --------      --------      --------     --------
```

The first program is saying "swap the residents of two houses":

```
    ______        _____         ______       ______
   /______\      /______\      /______\     /______\
 2 |Smith |    4 | Bond |    6 |Jones |   8 | Solo |
   --------      --------      --------     --------
```

While the second is saying "swap the numbers on the houses":

```
    ______        _____         ______       ______
   /______\      /______\      /______\     /______\
 2 |Smith |    6 |Jones |    4 | Bond |   8 | Solo |
   --------      --------      --------     --------
```

Comment: yes, with pic I got some clarity. But still question is in ur diagram , u told Bond address 4, Jones address 6 for 1st program........ And in 2nd program John address 6 and Bond address 4, then where is exact difference, though both have same address. In C program , all values put in some addresses, right??

Comment: @Srestha The difference is that in the second program you only swap the values of two variables that are local to a function (which happen to be pointers), while in the first you swap the values that the pointers point to.

Comment: Ur last statement is clear to me. "in the second program you only swap the values of two variables". and "in the first you swap the values that the pointers point to."  means?

Answer (score 2):

> In the second program pointer is swapping means address are also
>   swapping. Right?? But it doesn't affect on value. While in 1st program
>   , address and pointer is swapped and at the mean time values also
>   swapped. But Why??

Because

```
void mystery (int *ptra, int *ptrb) {  
     int *temp; 
     temp = ptrb;  
     ptrb =ptra; 
     ptra = temp; 
}
```

The above program swaps the contents of `ptra` and `ptrb` not the contents of objects where `ptra` and `ptrb` is pointing since `ptra` and `ptrb` are local to `mystery` function.

---

**To represent it pictorially.**

Consider `a` and `b` are stored at address `100` and `200`.

After     `mystery (&a, &b);` call.

`ptra` will be pointing to `a` by storing `100` into it.
and `ptrb` will be pointing to `b` by storing `200` into it.

```
     ptra       100
   +-----+     +---+
   | 100 |     | 1 | 
   +-----+     +---+
     ptrb       200
   +-----+     +---+
   |200  |     | 2 | 
   +-----+     +---+
```

When function finishes its execution.

`ptra` will be pointing to `b` by storing `200` into it.
and `ptrb` will be pointing to `a` by storing `100` into it.

```
    ptra        100
   +-----+     +---+
   | 200 |     | 1 | 
   +-----+     +---+
    ptrb        200
   +-----+     +---+
   |100  |     | 2 | 
   +-----+     +---+
```

Comment: yes, So, content of pointer changes, but it has no effect on "mystery (&a, &d); " While 1st program while returning swap performed successfully

Comment: What did you understand from my answer?

Comment: In ur answer "the contents of ptra and ptrb not the contents of objects where ptra and ptrb", this line not clear me :(

Comment: `ptra` and `ptrb` will hold the address of  `a` and `b` when you swap them you are just swapping the `ptra` and `ptrb` ) not the contents of address where they are pointing.

Comment: According to ur diagram, at first ptra pointing to 1 and ptrb pointing to 2. But in ur last diagram ptra pointing to 2 and ptrb pointing to 1. Then ptra and ptrb value swapped too. right? But when returning it has showing no swap. 2016 and 42, while returning also getting 2016 and 42.

Comment: But In the same time , can u plz explain 1st program too?? Here pointer a, b  and variable c are local too that function. Still it able to swap,  we are sending 5, 6 and getting return as 6,5. right??

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet you change the values of the objects which are not local in this function scope - defined in the main and referenced by those pointers.

In the second one you change the local variables which stop to exists when you leave the function.

Comment: "you change the values of the objects which are not local"- Can u elaborate this portion of ur answer??

Comment: Very simple . The pointers point subjects which will still exists after function return. In the second snippet you only swap local variables but not the referenced objects itself.

Comment: @P__J__ We may need to come up with layman's example :D I'm trying hard to explain him the concept.

Comment: @P_J_ in 1st snippet also all variable and pointer is local too. right?? Then why it's referential object get swapped??

Comment: @Srestha learn a bit about the pointers.  Pointer is a stick you touch the ball. Does ball change if you throw away the stick? But if you tell your friend to change the ball you point using the stick , the ball will be different. After that you can throw away the stick.

Comment: @P__J__  ok, I got. then in 1st program we took two sticks and another ball as temp. Right?? Then here if both stick throws , then how the ball changes??

Comment: I will try even simpler. You have two boxes. In one you have red ball in another blue. Two sticks. One box more. Ball has to always in the box. You point using sticks two  boxes and order the swap. Boxes are the same balls are different. Box is variable and the ball it's value.

Comment: Second case same boxes and balls you swap the sticks in  your hands. Does it change the content of the Box?